# Android Studio fails to update every time on Mac

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, android-studio-4.0

I've been updating Android studio since version 3 and every time it's the same thing, it downloads the update, restarts and then when it opens up again it's still the same version...nothing has changed. And to top it off there's even the same notification that I need to update again.

Using High Sierra OS although it was happened on the previous OS too. Right now I have version 4.01 so I try to update to 4.2. I do so and once it's installed the update it re-opens Android Studio and the version still shows 4.01. Am I doing something wrong or what?

Up until now I always have to manually download the new version and reinstall it over this version. I always assume they would have fixed this problem in the new version but after going from version 3 all the way to 4 with the problem still here it seems they will not fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [JetBrains Toolbox](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update) for that

Comment: Works for me, thanks

Comment: Me too, thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. Just create an empty project and check for updates from there. That way after downloading the patches I have a restart button in the Event Log window and it works well. It updated and restarted the studio normally not like outside of project where it cannot launch after update. Regards!

Comment: That's not the problem I'm having, it always DOES restart after updating, the problem is it's not updated after the restart.

Comment: I tried what you said anyway, updating with a project open but it still shows version 4.0.1 after updating. Makes no difference..

Comment: It worked for you because you have a completely different problem to me...